# Rules in iOS mail

Tags: ios, mail.app

Is there a way to set up simple rules (*When subject contains “foobar“ move Mail to trash.*) in Mail.app on iOS 13?

Comment: What mail service do you use?  It’s better to do this type of thing at the server (Gmail, Outlook.com, Yahoo, etc)  rather than let the client (Mail) deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is block the sender from sending messages to you. This is done in Settings/Mail.  This will block email, phone calls, etc from the blocked site. This is available on iOS 13 and later.

> Ignore Blocked Senders can now be enabled in Settings > Mail. The blocked contacts list is shared with Messages, FaceTime, and Phone. (50775961)

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-13-release-notes

See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible on iOS 17 and iPadOS 17. Open Settings > [Your Name] > iCloud > iCloud Mail > iCloud Mail Rules.

[image]

[image]